# Would this be a good solution to avoid short-circuit evaluation?

Tags: java, short-circuiting

I am new in programming and have been recently learning Java by myself. While I was studying, I came into a problem that wants me to find a way to avoid Short-Circuit Evaluation. I came up with two solutions that either maintains or breaks the SCE. I want to know which one would be more preferable answer in real work situations.

I have first tried separating the computation of int variables from the logical operators. Although it worked and maintained the SCE, I wanted to reduce the number of lines for my coding. So I came up with a code that is shorter but breaks up the SCE.

//the given problem

```
int n1 = 0, n2 = 0;
boolean result = ((n1 += 10) < 0) && (num2 +=10) > 0); // false, n1 = 10, n2 = 0
```

//first answer

```
int n1 = 0, n2 = 0;
n += 10; n2 += 10; 
boolean result = (n1 < 0) && (n2 > 0); // n1=10, n2=10, false
```

//shorter code

```
boolean result = !(!((n1 += 10)<0) && (n2 +=10)>0); // false, n1=10, n2=10
```

Although both answers show the same result, shoud I keep SCE alive or aim for shorter coding? I hope my question makes sense.

Comment: Are you familiar with the `&` operator (which isn't short-circuiting)?

Comment: In a real work situation none of these would be valid. Variable names `n1`, `n2` and `result` make it impossible to know what's happening without examining the code carefully. Programming is rarely about finding the fastest way or the shortest code, far more important is that other people can read and understand it quickly, and that there are no hidden traps that one might fall into when modifying that code.

Comment: "_I want to know which one would be more preferable answer in real work situations._" The first answer for sure (with proper variable names of course!!). Usually you want to avoid using `+=`, `++`, etc. operations inside an if-statement. So first increasing both `n1` and `n2` and only then doing the check would be preferable if they both have to be increased. If the result of "_the given problem_" was intended, I'd still split it up into first increasing `n1`; then doing the `n1 < 0` check; then increasing `n2`; then doing the `n2` check.

Comment: As for the _shorter code_, a double negative like that looks very confusing. Code should be pretty clear the moment you lay your eyes on it, without needing to analyze every part of it. PS/off-topic: In [code-golfing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf/info) (completing a certain task/challenge in as few bytes as possible), I would indeed use the bitwise-AND `&`, which will evaluate everything first; as well as remove spaces, use single-byte variables, and use Java's 11+ `var`: `var r=(a+=10)<0&(b+=10)>0;`. **NEVER** do something like this in non-code-golfing programs of course!